# Take four numbers onclick of an image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have pictures that represents from 1 to 9, and I want that when the user clicks one of them save the number (example: If the user clicks on the image that has a 1, save the number 1), but I only need four numbers for the password. How can I make the user to only put four digits in one variable?

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <title>Hora</title>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csshora.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var number;
            function changeImage(a) {
                document.getElementById("img").src=a;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="login">
          <img src="img/1.png" class="i-1" onclick='number('1')'/>
          <img src="img/2.png" class="i-2" />
          <img src="img/3.png" class="i-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" class="i-4" />
          <img src="img/5.png" class="i-5" />
          <img src="img/6.png" class="i-6" />
          <img src="img/7.png" class="i-7" />
          <img src="img/8.png" class="i-8" />
          <img src="img/9.png" class="i-9" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: doble quote problem (onclick='number('1')') and change the name of the function "number" for possibles name's errors. Show the code you tried.

Comment: I know it is an error, but I didn't tried anything else because I don't know how to do it, i just tried to set the var numbre to the number the uses clicks but i will need 9 vars

Comment: @almartinez My answer probably resolves your query please check..

Comment: The HTML is not well-formed: The `<title>` tag is outside the `<head>` tag. You may want to use [the HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494130&charset=utf-8) (replace the URI with yours or fill in the *Document URL* field on that page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example to get started.

```html
<html>
<title>Hora</title>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csshora.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var number;
    var pin = "";

    function changeImage(a) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = a;
    }

    function number(v) {
      if (pin.length <= 3) {
        pin += v;
      } else
        alert('You have already entered 4 digits');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
    <img src="img/1.png" class="i-1" onclick="number('1')" />
    <img src="img/2.png" class="i-2" onclick="number('2')" />
    <img src="img/3.png" class="i-3" onclick="number('3')" />
    <img src="img/4.png" class="i-4" onclick="number('4')" />
    <img src="img/5.png" class="i-5" onclick="number('5')" />
    <img src="img/6.png" class="i-6" onclick="number('6')" />
    <img src="img/7.png" class="i-7" onclick="number('7')" />
    <img src="img/8.png" class="i-8" onclick="number('8')" />
    <img src="img/9.png" class="i-9" onclick="number('9')" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: no, thanks for answering but it's not what i wanted, i want to concat them into one numer of 4 digits

Comment: @almartinez : It exactly does what you want. Check the updated answer.

Comment: yes, thanks, now i dont want the log to show the number because it's a password, then i will compare it to predifend password, anyway to do it or just take the variable pin == (password that the user has)

Comment: @almartinez : It's just for your understanding. Remove `console.log('Current pin: ' + pin);` and modify `console.log('You have already entered 4 digits');` to `alert('You have already entered 4 digits');`

Comment: The variable `pin` is the password.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

```js
var numbers = 0;
var code = "";

function makeNumber(num)
{
  if(numbers < 4)
  {
    numbers++;
    code+=""+num;
  }
  else
  {
    alert("No more");
  }
}

function showCode()
{
  alert(code);
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <img height="20" width="20" src="http://icdn.pro/images/en/b/l/blue-ball-icone-9872-128.png" class="i-1" onclick='makeNumber(1);'/>
  <img height="20" width="20" src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/play-stop-pause/stop-normal-blue.png" class="i-2" onclick='makeNumber(2);'/>
  <img height="20" width="20" src="http://www.teconic.com/graphics/blue_ball.jpg" class="i-3" onclick='makeNumber(3);'/>
  <img height="20" width="20" src="https://bellcomputers.nz/imag/alternative.png" class="i-4" onclick='makeNumber(4);'/>
  <img height="20" width="20" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/t/K/e/5/8/blue-stop-md.png" class="i-5" onclick='makeNumber(5);'/>
  <img height="20" width="20" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1838/tropical_stuff/128/ball.png" class="i-6" onclick='makeNumber(6);'/>
</div>

<button onClick="showCode();">Show Code</button>
```

Here we maintain a counter that restricts more than four image click selections.

Comment: checked it, yes it does some of the job that i want to do, i vote you but doesnt do all that i want, anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: @almartinez sure.. ping me if you have any further issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this and tell me if is that you are looking for *(only the first two images)*:

```html
<html>
    <title>Hora</title>
    <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csshora.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var number;
            var pass = '';
            function changeImage(a) {
                document.getElementById("img").src=a;
            }
            function createPass(e){
              if(pass.length>=4){
              }else{
                pass = pass+e;
              }
              console.log(pass);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="login">
            <img src="img/1.png" class="i-1" onclick='createPass("1")'/>
            <img src="img/2.png" class="i-2" onclick='createPass("2")'/>
            <img src="img/3.png" class="i-3" />
            <img src="img/4.png" class="i-4" />
            <img src="img/5.png" class="i-5" />
            <img src="img/6.png" class="i-6" />
            <img src="img/7.png" class="i-7" />
            <img src="img/8.png" class="i-8" />
            <img src="img/9.png" class="i-9" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but dont show the numers cuz it is a password, then i will compare it with the password for each user